# Integration of $f(x)=\exp(-ax-b\sin^{-1}(cx))$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

Is there an analytical solution for the following integral?

> $$\int \exp(-ax-b\sin^{-1}(cx)) dx$$

Mathematica was unable to solve it, and I tried myself by integration by parts but without success.

Comment: Very little hope, I guess.

Comment: Thanks anyways for taking a look @Claude Leibovici.

Comment: if $a=0$ there is a closed form

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a,b,c\neq0$ for the key case:

Let $u=\sin^{-1}(cx)$ ,

Then $x=\dfrac{\sin u}{c}$

$\therefore\int e^{-ax-b\sin^{-1}(cx)}~dx$

$=\int e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}}e^{-bu}~d\left(\dfrac{\sin u}{c}\right)$

$=-\dfrac{1}{a}\int e^{-bu}~d\left(e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}}\right)$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}-bu}}{a}+\dfrac{1}{a}\int e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}}~d\left(e^{-bu}\right)$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}-bu}}{a}-\dfrac{b}{a}\int e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}}e^{-bu}~du$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}-bu}}{a}-\dfrac{b}{a}\int\left(e^{-bu}+\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{a^{2n}e^{-bu}\sin^{2n}u}{c^{2n}(2n)!}\right)~du+\dfrac{b}{a}\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^{2n+1}e^{-bu}\sin^{2n+1}u}{c^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}~du$

$=-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}-bu}}{a}-\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{C_n^{2n}a^{2n-1}be^{-bu}}{4^nc^{2n}(2n)!}~du-\int\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kC_{n+k}^{2n}a^{2n-1}be^{-bu}\cos2ku}{2^{2n-1}c^{2n}(2n)!}~du+\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^kC_{n+k+1}^{2n+1}a^{2n}be^{-bu}\sin((2k+1)u)}{4^nc^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}~du$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Power-reduction_formulae)

$=-\dfrac{e^{-\frac{a\sin u}{c}-bu}}{a}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{a^{2n-1}e^{-bu}}{4^nc^{2n}(n!)^2}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^ka^{2n-1}be^{-bu}(2k\sin2ku-b\cos2ku)}{2^{2n-1}c^{2n}(n+k)!(n-k)!(b^2+4k^2)}~du-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^ka^{2n}be^{-bu}(b\sin((2k+1)u)+(2k+1)\cos((2k+1)u)}{4^nc^{2n+1}(n+k+1)!(n-k)!(b^2+(2k+1)^2)}+C$ (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions#Integrals_involving_exponential_and_trigonometric_functions)

$=\dfrac{e^{-b\sin^{-1}(cx)}}{a}I_0\left(\dfrac{a}{c}\right)-\dfrac{e^{-ax-b\sin^{-1}(cx)}}{a}-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\dfrac{(-1)^ka^{2n-1}be^{-bu}(2k\sin(2k\sin^{-1}(cx))-b\cos(2k\sin^{-1}(cx)))}{2^{2n-1}c^{2n}(n+k)!(n-k)!(b^2+4k^2)}~du-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sum\limits_{k=0}^n\dfrac{(-1)^ka^{2n}be^{-bu}(b\sin((2k+1)\sin^{-1}(cx))+(2k+1)\cos((2k+1)\sin^{-1}(cx))}{4^nc^{2n+1}(n+k+1)!(n-k)!(b^2+(2k+1)^2)}+C$

Comment: I now realize that my earlier attempts at summing the above series were incorrect. It is not very clear to me which limit the series does converges to. Could you please elaborate further on your hint?